# How monitoring Postgres replications?

Tags: monitoring, database-replication, postgresql-9.6

I have clasters postgres 9.6.15 and 9.6.20 (streaming replications)
In to 9.6.15 for master node

```
pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp();   
pg_last_xlog_receive_location();
pg_last_xlog_replay_location();
```

is empty In to 9.6.20 for master node

> pg_last_xlog_receive_location - is empty
>
> pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp - have time start replications
>
> pg_last_xlog_replay_location  - have value, but != SELECT
> sent_location FROM pg_stat_replication s;

Cluster replications is work.

```
SELECT client_addr,pg_xlog_location_diff(s.sent_location,s.replay_location) byte_lag FROM pg_stat_replication s;
have byte_lag = 0
```

Why

```
pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp();
pg_last_xlog_receive_location();
pg_last_xlog_replay_location();
```

is empty from working replications?
How to monitor Posrgres cluster replications?

Answer (score 0):

http://eulerto.blogspot.com/2011/11/understanding-wal-nomenclature.html
`pg_last_xlog_receive_location()` and `pg_last_xlog_replay_location()` need monitor in the replica.